# Instantiating an ifstream object without using a variable

Tags: c++, templates, iostream

I can't seem to open a file without storing it in a variable. I can do this:

```
ifstream blob("somefile");
string line;
blob >> line;
```

But when I try this:

```
string line;
ifstream("somefile") >> line;
```

The compiler (clang) gives this error:

```
t.cpp:7:23: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('ifstream' (aka 'basic_ifstream<char>') and 'string' (aka 'basic_string<char>'))
    ifstream("thing") >> i;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~
In file included from t.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream:39:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:39:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/ios:42:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ios_base.h:42:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_classes.h:41:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/string:53:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2679:5: note: candidate function [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>] not
      viable: no known conversion from 'ifstream' (aka 'basic_ifstream<char>') to 'basic_istream<char> &' for 1st argument
    operator>>(basic_istream<char>& __is, basic_string<char>& __str);
    ^
In file included from t.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream:40:
/    usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:121:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') to
      '__istream_type &(*)(__istream_type &)' for 1st argument
      operator>>(__istream_type& (*__pf)(__istream_type&))
      ^
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:125:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion 

... a few more hundred pages of crap ...

1 error generated.
```

So, what's the difference between the two? With other classes, calling it directly works just fine. Is there some template magic involved that makes it ambiguous?

Comment: @Kerrek: Why did you delete it?!

Comment: @KerrekSB I agree with Tomalak, looks like the answer to me.

Comment: Oddly, (or perhaps not so oddly), this works fine in VC10.  Maybe that's why Kerrek deleted his answer.  VC10 is not compliant in this case.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley:  In fact, Visual C++ is compliant.  The specification of the `operator>>` overload has changed in C++11.

Comment: My original error message was actually something completely unrelated (missing header file). I've pasted in the correct error message now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that you post is not valid in C++03 (i.e., what was the C++ language standard until September 2011).  In C++03, there is only one overload of `operator>>` that might be considered here [I've removed all of the template code because it is not relevant]:

```
istream& operator>>(istream&, string&);
```

Note that the `std::istream` parameter is a non-const reference, so a temporary `std::istream` object cannot be used.  In your code, you are trying to use a temporary object there.

In C++11 (i.e., the current C++ language standard), there is an additional overload which takes the `std::istream` object by rvalue reference.  This allows either a temporary to be passed via that parameter.

Visual C++ already supports this feature of C++11, which is why, as Benjamin Lindley points out in a comment, your code will indeed compile if you use Visual C++ 2010 or later.  Your build of Clang *may* support this if you use the **-std=c++0x** flag.

Comment: Interestingly, the `<string>` header synopsis in 21.3 is inconsistent with the specification of the overloads in 21.4.8.9.

Comment: I've notified WG21 of the specification inconsistency.  In the meantime, for C++11, I think it is reasonable to assume that there should be two overloads of `operator>>`, one taking an `istream&`, the other taking an `istream&&`.